# Get Jclass or jobject from jobject array JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have my below Java code where Array is a custom object.

```
public native int pax_store_get_data_avail_info(DataAvailable[] stats_array);
```

My JNI Generated file is

```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_pax_1store_1get_1data_1avail_1info
      (JNIEnv *env, jclass jclass1, jobjectArray jobj){
}
```

I want to populate jobjectArray inside the JNI ,and when I tried using my implemention my program crashed .

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_pax_1store_1get_1data_1avail_1info
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jclass1, jobjectArray jobj){


struct pax_store_data_avail_stat_s test_stat [2] ;

    int i;

    test_stat [0].time = 1460332625;  //  4/10/2016, 4:57:05 PM
    test_stat [0].bytes_in_this_second = 20;

    test_stat [1].time = 1460332626;   //  4/10/2016, 4:57:06 PM 
    test_stat [1].bytes_in_this_second = 30;
    jclass dataClass=(*env)->GetObjectClass(env,"demo/DataAvailable");//Crash Over here
```

I was not able to get the Object Class .So taught on if I get the jclass or jobject from the Jobject Array .

Are there any other methods from which I can populate the Jobject Array inside the JNI code .

Comment: Have you considered *consulting the documentation?* You're using `GetObjectClass()` in a way that isn't documented, so of course it doesn't work, and yet that method is the answer to your question, when used correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `jobject` you can use `GetObjectClass` to retrieve the class of the object:

```
jobject object = ...
jclass c =(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, object);
```

Obviously passing a class name does not work. Instead - given a class name - use `FindClass` to obtain the `jclass`:

```
jclass c =(*env)->FindClass(env, "demo/DataAvailable");
```